# Distinguir entre un enlace mandado por XMLHttpRequest y por usuario al navegador

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Yo quiero que, al reproducir un video en mi página, un contador suba, para eso la pagina con el video tiene el código:

```
player.on('play', function(data) {
    if (swap[0]==true) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/play.php?name=3historasdeterror);
        xhttp.send();
        swap[0]=false;
        console.log("funciona");
    }
});
```

Y el archivo play.php tiene este:

```
<?php
$access = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","****","****","****");
$access -> query("update visits set play = play+1 where name = '".$_GET['name']."'"); 
$access -> close();
?>
```

El problema de la inyeccion es otro tema, eso ya se como se resuelve, el asunto aquí es que un troll puede tomar el enlace que figuraría en el codigo fuente cargado `http://localhost/play.php?name=3historasdeterror` (por supuesto si el dominio no fuese localhost) y la puede introducir directamente en el navegador repetidas veces e inflar mis conteos, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que el `play.php` distinga de dónde proviene el envío del enlace?

Sospecho que se podría hacer si ubico el archivo fuera de la carpeta pública, pero tampoco sé como hacer que el request envíe el enlace a un archivo fuera de la carpeta pública.

Comment: ¿Por que usas Ajax para esto? Y, para controlar el número de visualizaciones (visitas) es mucho más seguro usar servicios como Google Analytics, que te permite usar una API para registro (en la base de datos) y manejo de visitas reales en cualquier URL de tu sitio web.

Comment: @A.Cedano simpleza quizá, además creo que hay que depender de google lo menos que se pueda, porque acapara todo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

### 1. Enviar encabezado personalizado

Usa el método [.setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) para agregar un encabezado personalizado:

```
player.on('play', function(data) {
    if (swap[0]==true) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/play.php?name=3historasdeterror");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader('AJAX', 'true');
        xhttp.send();
        swap[0]=false;
        console.log("funciona");
    }
});
```

En PHP usas [getallheaders()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.getallheaders.php) para obtener los encabezados y comparar; es probable que se agregue el prefijo `HTTP_`:

```
<?php
$headers = getallheaders();
// Asignar a una variable para saber que la petición es por AJAX
$ajax = (isset($headers['AJAX']) || isset($headers['HTTP_AJAX']));
// Analizar resultado
if($ajax) {
    // La petición es por AJAX
} else {
    // Se trata de una petición normal
}
```

### 2. Agregar una variable a la URL

Simplemente agregas `&ajax=true` al final de la URL.

**Nota:** Luego de leer nuevamente tu pregunta, creo que esta opción no sería tan viable para evitar incremento de contadores.

```
player.on('play', function(data) {
    if (swap[0]==true) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/play.php?name=3historasdeterror&ajax=true");
        xhttp.send();
        swap[0]=false;
        console.log("funciona");
    }
});
```

En PHP solo verificas si existe la variable

```
<?php
$ajax = (isset($_GET['ajax']));
// Analizar resultado
if($ajax) {
    // La petición es por AJAX
} else {
    // Se trata de una petición normal
}
```

Ten en cuenta que hay herramientas que permiten a los usuarios simular peticiones AJAX y no hay una forma 100% efectiva de evitar el incremento de contadores, pero al menos puedes lidiar con usuarios de escasos conocimientos del tema.

Comment: No funciona ninguna de tus dos opciones. ¿Supuestamente el codigo de play.php lo debía introducir bajo la primera llave del `if`?

Comment: @ArturoViñasSalazar, por favor edita tu pregunta para poner el código actualizado y explicar a qué te refieres con _"no funciona"_, si aparece algún error, no muestra nada o qué está pasando.

Comment: @ArturoViñasSalazar, no se puede saber el problema hasta que pongas el nuevo código en tu pregunta.

Comment: esperame un poco, si con esto no encuentras el problema, te pondre el codigo, pero antes el `console.log` me daba el mensaje que programé cuando daba el play, ahora desde que añado el `xhttp.setRequestHeader('AJAX', 'true');` ya no me sale el mansaje de la consola, o sea que el error está en el comienzo.

Comment: @ArturoViñasSalazar, si estás viendo la consola, debió aparecer error, mencionando que no se pueden enviar encabezados hasta que se abra la conexión. Solo coloca el encabezado después de `.open()` y debe funcionar. De cualquier forma, actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Ahora sí funciona, gracias.

Comment: tengo que aclarar que en algunos sistemas, `getallheaders()`  no te devuelve la variable ajax con mayusculas `AJAX`, sino capitalizada `Ajax`